# Config to re-enable gtk2 tear-off menus?

Tags: gui, desktop, gtk2

Following an apt-get update on Debian jessie/sid, several Gtk2 applications no longer have tear-off menus enabled.

I'm aware that this is a [deprecated capability of Gtk](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTearoffMenuItem.html) (and disagree strongly with the GNOME team's rational for deprecating the feature), but if this *is* a config issue (and I've dug it up repeatedly in the past), how would I re-enable it?

gconf-editor doesn't seem to affect the behavior.

Comment: Presumably this is because newer versions of those applications have removed the depreciated code, in which case there is absolutely nothing you can do.  Features which no longer exist are not "disabled", they are *gone*.  You could always scan sources yourself to check if the depreciated calls are really gone, and/or check their news and changelog records for relevant versions.  But I do not think they have, or could, be disabled system wide. "Depreciated" generally means we discourage this but provide backward compatibility, and warns that it may be removed in future versions of the library.

Comment: Unless the underlying libraries have changed, the feature still ought to be there.  I'm ... confused as to where the hell it went.

Comment: The fact that the feature is still part of the underlying library does not mean it is part of any particular application.  As whatever applications have evolved, their authors have *removed depreciated code*, meaning those applications no longer contain any reference to depreciated features in the library.   I.e., by *gone* I mean from the application, not the library.  But that is still irreversibly gone, unless you want to fork it and put the code back yourself. If you name a (small, please) example app with version number, I can try to verify this thesis for you.

Comment: FYI for the commenters - I'm sure I recall that the tearoff feature of gtk menus was never an application choice - that is an application didn't instruct gtk to enable tearoff. It was a gtk configuration item where gtk would go to .gtkrc to decide whether to enable tearoff features irrespective of the application it was in.